# Python: Issue reading and writing with formulas from one excel sheet to another. Using openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, excel, excel-formula, openpyxl

I am new to programming and have a question with python, openpyxl, and formulas. At the moment, I am trying to use a formula to sum multiple cells on one excel sheet (xlsx), read it, and write it to another excel sheet. This is my current code:

```
# Give the location of the Departments Report
path4 = "Departments - June 29, 2021 to June 29, 2021.xlsx"

# To open the workbook
# workbook object is created
wb4 = openpyxl.load_workbook(path4)

# Get workbook active sheet object
# from the active attribute
ws5 = wb4.active

# Cell object is created by using
# sheet object's wb[] method.
ws5['I100'] = "=SUM(I8:I99)"
Dc1 = ws5['I100']

# Give the location of the write file
path2 = "Daily Financials.xlsx"

# To open the workbook
# workbook object is created
wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook(path2)

# Get desired workbook sheet
ws6 = wb2["COS"]

# Cell is specified with value
ws6["CK7"].value = Dc1.value

# Finally, save and close the Excel file
# via the save() and close() method.
wb2.save('Daily Financials.xlsx')
wb2.close()
```

There are no errors when running the code, however, the formula is written on the new excel sheet as "=SUM(I8:I99)" and not the value of those from the first excel sheet. I have looked around and tried adding ".value", but I am struggling to figure this out.

[Current excel output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZHYq.png)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It quite clearly states in the documentation that openpyxl never evaluates formulae. https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#using-formulae

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's covered by the library documentation.

Comment: That information is helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using **python**, I suggest a loop that will put the actual data (not formula) into the cell in ws5:

```py
# Cell object is created by using
# sheet object's wb[] method.
counter = 0
for c in ws5['I8:I99']:
    counter += c[0].value
ws5['I100'] = counter
#or with list comprehension: ws5['I100'] = sum([c[0].value for c in ws5['I8:I99']])
Dc1 = ws5['I100']
```